# PHP to email form: 'spam' issue, validation, alert box

Tags: php, html, css, validation, error-handling

I've spent a lot of time trying out things I found on stackoverflow but I don't seem to be able to find what I'm looking.

I will also say that my knowledge of PHP/JavaScript is basic as this is not what i'm usually involved in.

I've got a very simple contact form:

```
  <form action=' ' method='post'>

    <label for='firstName' >First Name: </label>
    <input type='text' name='firstName' id='firstName' />

    <label for='lastName' >Last Name: </label>
    <input type='text' name='lastName' id='lastName' />

    <label for='phone' >Contact No :</label>
    <input type='text' name='phone' id='phone' />

    <label for='email' >Email Address:</label>
    <input type='text' name='email' id='email' />

    <input type='image' id="submit" src="images/submit.png" class="uibutton" onclick="show_alert()" />

  </form>
```

And this is my PHP:

```
<?php
```

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

```
$field_name = $_POST['firstName'];
$field_surname = $_POST['lastName'];
$field_phone = $_POST['phone'];
$reply_to = $_POST['email'];


//send email
$mail_to = 'me.pfrrr@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Contact a site visitor '.$field_name." ".$field_surname;

$body_message = 'First Name: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'Last Name: '.$field_surname."\n";
$body_message .= 'Phone Number: '.$field_phone."\n";
$body_message .= 'Email Address: '.$reply_to;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_name."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
```

}
?>

I want my form to send me an email. It does that; however the email I receive always goes into 'spam' folder. The domain/IP are not on PBL list.

I would appreciate if someone can at least give me a direction how to achieve the following and answer some questions:

1. I want to get email to go into 'inbox' folder

2.I want to validate the form, but I want my errors to appear under the text field. I can do this with tools provided by Dreamweaver; however it still lets me to submit an empty form. Is there a way I can use php/html/css to display errors in an aesthetic way? (on the same page > under each text field)

3.On 'submit' I've got an alert box saying 'thank you'. How can I make the alert box pop up only when the form is correctly filled in?

I would be really grateful for 'proper' answers (not: 'go and read php/javascript tutorials' type of thing, as I've done that, tried things, they haven't worked - so I need further advice )

Thank you   :)

Comment: You should probably post each of those questions seperately

Comment: Check the headers in the emails that were 'spammed' - there's usually spam filter scoring information that can tell you exactly WHY the spam filter triggered. Beyond that, don't use the PHP mail() function. It's a very basic piece of garbage that barely works on a good day. Use a more full-featured mailer, like PHPMailer or Swiftmailer.

Comment: I'd suggest formatting your From better. It should be "From: $field_name <$reply_to>\r\n". That could be triggering the spam filter.

Answer (score 2):

1. If this is just going to your email, add the from address to you contacts. that will override any spam filters.
2. If you want to require fields, you can use [html5 form validation](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/). You can also use those to check for a valid email address.
3. Move your javascript from the button `onclick=""` to `onsubmit=""` in your `<form>` tag.